# jQuery - input with a select & options, better way?

Tags: jquery, input, html-select

First, take a look at my fiddle: [my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66qd546c/)

Is there an easier way, to do it?

My way works fine, but I'm not happy yet :)

```
javascript

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#input").click(function(){
            $("#selectives").css('display', 'block'); // displays block "div #selectives" underneath
            $("input").css('borderRadius', '2px 2px 0px 0px'); // not that important.. just css
        });


        $(".auswahl").click(function(){ // .auswahl (every li element)
            var thisWord = $(this).html(); // thisWord = the word u want to get the value of
            $("#input").val(thisWord); // puts the value of "thisWord" into the #input
            $("#selectives").css('display', 'none'); // immediately if you click an li element, it should disappear
            $("input").css('borderRadius', '2px'); // not that important.. just css
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var input = $("#input");
  var list = $("#selectives");
        input.click(function(){
            list.toggle(); // displays block "div #selectives" underneath
            input.toggleClass('open'); // not that important.. just css
        });


        list.on("click", "li",function(){ // .auswahl (every li element)
            input.val($(this).text()); // puts the value of "thisWord" into the #input
            list.toggle();
            input.toggleClass('open');
        });

    });
```

css:

```
.open{
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
}
```

fork:https://jsfiddle.net/q7jg1e0a/2/

I think it is better to save element into variable. So you don't have to look for it every time. (could slow you script down. Especially if you have large DOM).

And I think it is better to use classes, than manipulate css in code. It is easier to change it on one place in css then look for it in code.

Also if you do only opening and closing, you can use toggle and it will do the hard work of finding out the state for you. Not mega necessary in your code...

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! I'll try to use more variables & classes now.

Answer (score 0):

Was a bit late in answering, but posting it anyway instead of throwing it away right out :D. Much the same reasoning as the accepted answer, just with a separate function for showing/hiding (comments in the code)

```js
$(function(){
 var selectives =$("#selectives"), input = $("#input").click(showHide);
  function showHide(){ //single function for the show/hide behaviour
   selectives.toggle(); //show/hide the selectives block
    input.toggleClass('droppedDown');  //put the alternate style in a css class and toggle that
  }   
  selectives.find('li').click(function(){ //every li element inside the selectives div. (Negating the need for the auswahl class)
      showHide();   
      input.val($(this).text());
 });
});
```

```css
  body {height: 510px; font-family: Arial}
  #selectives {height: 10px; position: absolute; top: 31px; left: -32px; display: none;}
  #input {position: relative; }
  input:hover {cursor: pointer; }
  input::-moz-selection {background: white; color: #000}
  input {width: 107px; border-radius: 2px; border: 0.1em solid black; background-image:url(https://image.freepik.com/freie-ikonen/doppelpfeil-ios-7-schnittstelle-symbol_318-35368.jpg); -webkit-appearance: none; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;}
  ul {margin-top: 0px;list-style-type: none; text-align: left;}
  li {width: 107px; border-color: black black orange black; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; padding: 5px; border-radius: 0px; font-size: 10px; border-top: 0px;}
  li:last-child {border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px; border: 1px solid black; border-top: 0px;}
  li:first-child {border-radius: 0px; border-bottom: 1px solid orange; border-top: 0px;}
  li:hover {background-color: ghostwhite; cursor: pointer;}
    
 .droppedDown{border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly id="input" type="text" value="Standard"> <!-- readonly = not being able to write -->
 <div id="selectives">
  <ul>
   <li>1</li> 
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```